# Accessibility: is this a valid use case for not having a keyboard listener with click handler?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have a tooltip widget which opens up on click of a button and clicking again on the trigger would close it.
For this, on the widget container div we add an `onclick` in which we stop the click event from bubbling to its parent using `e.stopPropagation()` otherwise clicking on the widget would trigger the click on its parent which would toggle the widget.

(This is similar to dropdown menu which is toggled on clicking on a trigger)

eslint a11y rule complains that this container with `onclick` should be also have at least one key event listener. What could be the key listener in this case? I am not using the `onclick` to provide any functionality that needs to be accessible through keyboard.

NOTE:
here is one of the exceptional cases as mentioned on the eslint plugin readme.
https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md#case-the-event-handler-is-only-being-used-to-capture-bubbled-events

This case is not the same, but similar.

Also, for reference, i opened an issue in the github repo.
https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/740

Comment: "I am not using the onclick to provide any functionality that needs to be accessible through keyboard." - define "needs". You need to be able to answer either that a) "keyboard-only users can already access this functionality by doing <xyz>", _or_ b) "this functionality is completely irrelevant to keyboard-only users, for reason <xyz>".

Comment: the functionality is to stop the click event propagation. There is no user functionality. I don't think this needs to be exposed through a key listener

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah this looks like a false alarm in that case.